# Weird Routing Issue in Laravel 4 and Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4, routes

I've got a weird routing issue with Laravel 4 and Nginx. I believe this is more than likely an Nginx issue, rather than Laravel.

Any route that exists can be accessed doing:

```
/index.php/route
```

Even stranger, anything preceding index.php will also work:

```
/abcdefg/abcdef/abcde/abcd/abc/ab/a/index.php/route
```

It doesn't matter how long the route is, as long as any segment that comes after index.php is correctly defined within routes.php.

The first example loads the correct route with CSS/JS etc but the second doesn't, it only loads the HTML.

Has anyone ever come across this and if so how can you stop this from happening, in both instances? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: OK folks, below is my Nginx config:

```
# Enable compression both for HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1.
gzip_http_version 1.1;

# Compression level (1-9).
# 5 is a perfect compromise between size and cpu usage, offering about
# 75% reduction for most ascii files (almost identical to level 9).
gzip_comp_level 5;

# Don't compress anything that's already small and unlikely to shrink much
# if at all (the default is 20 bytes, which is bad as that usually leads to
# larger files after gzipping).
gzip_min_length 500;

# Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
# identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront).
gzip_proxied any;

# Tell proxies to cache both the gzipped and regular version of a resource
# whenever the client's Accept-Encoding capabilities header varies;
# Avoids the issue where a non-gzip capable client (which is extremely rare
# today) would display gibberish if their proxy gave them the gzipped version.
gzip_vary on;

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types.
gzip_types application/atom+xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    if ($host = 'www.domain.com') {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default/4980/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default/4980/server.key;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
        # auth_basic_user_file  /home/forge/default/.htpasswd;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    # error_page 404 https://domain.com/404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Expire rules for static content

    # cache.appcache, your document html and data
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
    }

    # Feed
    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
      expires 1h;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
      expires 1y;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Comment: Please post the nginx configuration.

Comment: The first issue is a bug of sorts with Laravel, although not one that is likely to cause many issues. The second issue is likely a problem with your nginx configs.

Comment: Thanks guys, updated with my Nginx config.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK folks, looks like I have solved this issue. I initially tried using Route::filter to detect index.php and then perform a redirect but that didn't work, so instead I have used App::before like so:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (strpos($request->url(), 'index.php/'))
    {
        return Redirect::to(str_replace(['index.php/'], '', $request->url()), 301);
    }

    if (strpos($request->url(), 'index.php'))
    {
        return Redirect::to(str_replace(['index.php'], '', $request->url()), 301);
    }
});
```

This fixes both issues and redirects the request to a URI no longer containing index.php. Hope this helps others who may come accross this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your second location block to this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```